# How do secret rooms work in Wrath of the Lamb?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac, wrath-of-the-lamb

Without the DLC, the secret room would've been here guaranteed, as it's the only non-room area with three or more rooms around it:

[image]

Instead, I lose. I get nothing. Good day, sir. Why is that? What changed in the DLC?

Comment: This really shouldn't be a new question should it? We've already got a question on bomb-able walls, surely we can just update the question and answer (which is mine) for WotL? I was planning on updating it, just haven't got around to it yet.

Comment: @MrSmooth There's actually a few similar questions about the DLC as Yi Jiang noted - http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73142/how-can-i-find-the-secret-rooms-most-efficiently/73147#73147 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73142/how-can-i-find-the-secret-rooms-most-efficiently/73147#73147 - but they seem to mostly agree with the old wisdom of "look for a room surrounded by three or more other rooms"

Comment: @QAdp even so, it's a duplicate indicating that questions needs an updated answer. You could add a bounty there... This could of course be a bug, or another recent update's unfortunate effect

Comment: although I can confirm this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/X7W1m.png. Seems like we're doomed.

Comment: @Zommuter that can also happen pre-DLC - but if _and only if_ the level layout is such that there's no place for a room with three adjacent non-secret rooms. Also, "old" questions still apply to people without the DLC and don't need "updating."

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are all of the rules that determine where secret rooms appear?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73198/what-are-all-of-the-rules-that-determine-where-secret-rooms-appear)

Comment: @QAdp according to the changelog here: http://bindingofisaac.wikia.com/wiki/Version_History, the newest update screwed up secret and hidden rooms

Comment: @QAdp as murgatroid said, McMillen must have broken something in the last update; secret rooms are appearing in weird places, as you have already reported, and hidden rooms are nowhere to be found.

Comment: @QAppei they [are to be found](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X7W1m.png), but sometimes with two adjacent rooms. Maybe the top secret room spawned next to it somehow, I forgot to check that :-/

Comment: @Zommuter again, the one you keep linking to is normal and expected behavior, also found before the DLC.

Comment: @badp Thought about it a little, you should have tried to bomb the opposite wall: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7su.png. You would have found the secret room in the green spot and the hidden room in the red. Take a look [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73198/23609) and [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/73142/23609) to find why.

Comment: @Kappei good point. But wouldn't that in [my example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/X7W1m.png) mean the top secret room was only adjacent to the actual secret room?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Super-late answer go!

Secret Rooms always spawn adjacent to three different rooms whenever there is such a possibility. Super Secret Rooms try to border only one room, but they are **placed first.**

The answer is that the Secret Room is **either below the treasure room**, with a Super Secret Room below that, **or to the right of the shop**, with the Super Secret Room to the right of it.

And to answer a comment, as I can't comment yet:
@Kappei good point. But wouldn't that in my example mean the top secret room was only adjacent to the actual secret room? – Zommuter Jul 21 '12 at 7:06
No, it means that wherever the Super Secret Room is, like two squares below the chest for example, **it didn't create a possible location for the Secret Room** with three adjacent rooms. So from this you can conclude the Super Secret Room is not one square below and two to the right of the chest, as that would have resulted in the Secret Room being one below and to the right of the chest <inhale>.

Comment: ohhhh. That's evil.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this isn't a bug, you didn't find it.

Sometimes Secret Rooms are attached to curse rooms now, which confounds things a bit.

Comment: And by 'now', you mean, a specific version?

Comment: There's no curse rooms in that map.

Comment: That's a bug. have you tried updating / playing since?